Bootstrap Datepicker Range Selection by weekly
I am using bootstrap-datepicker.js to select date from Saturday to Friday of a week.
Date selection is working correctly but selected dates in the calendar is not correct.
If I select any date between sat and friday it should select whole week. this is not working properly
I have created a fiddle here
my whole code is here
function getSaturdayFriday(date) {
            const dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
            const diffToSaturday = dayOfWeek === 0 ? -6 : - (dayOfWeek + 1);;
            console.log(dayOfWeek);
            const saturday = new Date(date);
            if(dayOfWeek != 6) {
                saturday.setDate(date.getDate() + diffToSaturday);
            }
            //saturday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Set to midnight

            const friday = new Date(saturday);
            friday.setDate(saturday.getDate() + 6);
            //friday.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // Set to end of the day
            return { saturday, friday };
        }
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
            todayHighlight: true,
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
            const selectedDate = e.date;
            const { saturday, friday } = getSaturdayFriday(selectedDate);
            const options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
            const formattedDate = saturday.toLocaleDateString('en-CA', options).replace(/\//g, '-');
            const formattedEndDate = friday.toLocaleDateString('en-CA', options).replace(/\//g, '-');
            // $('#weaned_start_date').datepicker('clearDates');
            // $('#weaned_end_date').datepicker('clearDates');
            $('#weaned_start_date').datepicker('update', formattedDate);
            $('#weaned_end_date').datepicker('update',formattedEndDate);
            //$('#weaned_end_date').datepicker('update', formattedEndDate);

        });

I tried adding clearDates inside the changeDate it is looping infinite

If I select any date between sat and friday it should select whole week. this is not working properly : could you please specify with example? as I can see friday selection go with that week but saturday selection go for the next week which is correct. What you want now?
